# I need to understand the following JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I have the following vanilla JavaScript code. What I don't understand in the part `var removeClass = true;`

```
var arrow = document.getElementById('arrow');
var removeClass = true;
function turn(){
arrow.classList.toggle('rotate');
  removeClass = false;
}
function cls(){
if(removeClass){
    arrow.classList.remove('rotate');
}
   removeClass = true;
}
document.querySelector('#dropdown01').addEventListener('click', turn);
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', cls);
```

Here I rotate an arrow by 180 degrees when I click the dropdown and remove rotation when I click the body. It works. But I don't know how? And it is killing me. Help appreciated.

Comment: `removeClass` is only preventing the logic of removing the `rotate` class from the arrow if it is not rotated.  Given that if the class is not there, the remove would do nothing, not having that conditional wouldn't really change anything.

Comment: Would probably be a better practice to either not check at all and just try to remove the class, or to actually check the element to see if it has the class before removing it.  Making a secondary variable just to reflect the state of the element, when the element already holds the state, is fairly redundant

Comment: A better option would be to simply stop the event propagation in the "dropdown" handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is setting an initial value to removeClass.
When function turn() runs, it sets removeClass to false. Then when function cls() runs, it checks to see if 'removeClass' is true or false. 
So to put it simply, setting removeClass = true is just to make sure the correct value is placed on the variable on page load.

Answer (score 0):

That variable is being used to check wether the arrow is rotated or not. When you rotate it the first time using `turn()` your `removeClass` becomes `false` and you add the rotate class to your arrow (which, I assume, rotates it). When you rotate it back with `cls()`, it removes the rotate class and `removeClass` becomes true. That means that whenever `rotateClass` is true, the arrow is NOT turned.

That being said, the naming choice for that variable is not the best option the one who wrote the code could have chosen.